# Unexpected type * encountered while reading 'resources'. The type 'MappingToken' was expected

Tags: azure-pipelines

Running pipeline from template cause this error: `Unexpected type 'SequenceToken' encountered while reading 'resources'. The type 'MappingToken' was expected.` Any idea how to fix it?

**pipeline.yaml**

```yaml
trigger: none
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: pipeline
      type: git
      name: MyProject/my-repo
      # My feature branch
      ref: refs/heads/feature/unit_test
extends:
  # Template that I'm extending
  template: pipelines/application.yaml@pipeline
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem to this ridiculous error message. It turned out that when you extend pipelines with templates as I did `template: pipelines/application.yaml@pipeline`. You MUST get rid of `trigger` and `resources` keys in pipeline that you are extending it from.

**application.yaml** - Settings that caused the error.

```yaml
trigger:
  - pipeline

resources:
  - repo: self

variables:
  commit: '$(Build.SourceVersion)'
  imageTag: 'latest'
  imageName: 'app-backend'
  imageArtifact: '$(imageName):$(imageTag)'

stages:
  - template: ../stages/build.yaml
  - template: ../stages/test.yaml
```

**application.yaml** - Settings that fixed the error.

```yaml
variables:
  commit: '$(Build.SourceVersion)'
  imageTag: 'latest'
  imageName: 'app-backend'
  imageArtifact: '$(imageName):$(imageTag)'

stages:
  - template: ../stages/build.yaml
  - template: ../stages/test.yaml
```

Change makes sense since now your pipeline context is relative to your project, rather than the repository that you are extending it from.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar error like this one `System.ArgumentException: Unexpected type '' encountered while reading 'action manifest root'. The type 'MappingToken' was expected. at GitHub.DistributedTask.Objec...`

My mistake was that I put `'text"` instead of `'text'` or `"text"` ( typo error)

One typo line was enough to brake my workflow.